# Open anchor links in new tab.The link gets append with existing URL in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, struts, underscore.js

I have the following code in my underscore template

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.weather.com','_blank')"><%= element.description%></a></li>
```

and my currentPage URL is

```
    "http://localhost:9060/SampleApp/SampleServlet/Logon"
```

when i clicks the anchor it opens the link in new tab but it appends with the current URL ex)

```
    "http://localhost:9060/SampleApp/SampleServlet/Logon/www.weather.com"
```

How to open this page using new tab in chrome?Why the current URL gets appending with anchorURL??

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mre1okz0/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the element is an `a` element and you just want to open the link in new tab, use `src` and `target` attributes:

```
<li>
  <a href="http://www.weather.com" target="_blank">
   <%= element.description%>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: @lonica Bizau thank you for your fast reply.I tried this still the URL gets appended.

Comment: @VelNaga Probably a plugin/script removes `http://`? Please check out the HTML code from browser (dev tools).

Comment: @lonica Bizau in browser dev tools(Put F12 in chrome and checked the source).It contains the following code "<a href="https://www.weather.com" class="m-ui-link-inherit" target="_blank">weather zip code</a>"

Comment: Sorry it's a stackoverflow problem or i don't know how to post links in comments.It contains http.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open('www.weather.com','_blank')"><%= element.description%></a></li>
```

is not the same as

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.weather.com','_blank')"><%= element.description%></a></li>
```

If you use the url with `http://` it will not append the current url, but if you just use `www.***` there is no way to identified it as a full url. so it will append to the current url.

---

**EDIT**

Not sure why you are missing the HTTP:// part, but you can use following way,

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    if (!url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//)) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pt858puz/)

Comment: thank you for your reply.I know the difference i used http in my URL.But still it gets appended.

Comment: can you provide some online sample of your code to reproduce the issue

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's the same case for you, but for me I had a data-action="navigate" attribute on the anchor, so backbone was treating it like a route. Just removing data-action="navigate" worked for me.

Before:

```
<a href="http://www.weather.com" target="_blank" data-action="navigate">Go to Weather.com</a>
```

After:

```
<a href="http://www.weather.com" target="_blank">Go to Weather.com</a>
```

Comment: In my case, there was no data-action="navigate" in the anchor tag. But still it was happening as the question suggests